# How to create a stored procedure, with Spring JPA but without using Entities

Tags: spring, stored-procedures, spring-data-jpa

In a project that I am working with Spring and JPA, I need to call a stored procedure but it does not have any table stored on the application side, only an input parameter is sent and returns an output parameter to know if I finish the process.

In all examples with JPA it always relates to JPA entities and the BD Tables.

Thank you for your contributions.

Answer (score 0):

Take JPA out the pricture then. Assuming your application has a `Datasource` configured then inject that to the relevant code and get a connection:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html#getConnection()

Then just use standard JDBC.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/storedprocedures.html